# Gradle TestListener logging

Tags: testing, gradle, log4j, slf4j

I've written a GradleTestListener (implements `org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestListener`) and registered this in `build.gradle`:

```
test { addTestListener(new com.abcd.GradleTestAdaptor()) }
```

This test listener uses a third party library which is printing a warning + stacktrace via Slf4J to the console. This is causing a lot of noise in the test output so I would like to suppress it. I have configured Slf4j & Log4J as dependencies on my project and placed log4j.xml with root level error in src/test/resources. The warning is still being printed so it appears my logging configuration is not being picked up.

I'm wondering, as the `TestListener` is part of the build (akin to a plugin), will it pick up my logging configuration? If not, make it so?

Comment: It rather won't. This file holds configuration for the project itself, not for the build tool.

Comment: Thats what I thought. So is there a way for me to configure logging for the build tool?